# Automate saveas dialogue for IE11 (vba - IUIAutomation) Error Invalid pointer

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to download a file from IE11 using IUIAutomation but I get Error invalid pointer at the point @Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal Child)@. I had instal the dll and swich on the UIAutomationClient and VB Extensebility 5.3 on workbook reference.

```
Private Sub Download_complete_Click_Close()
Dim o As IUIAutomation
Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
Set o = New CUIAutomation
Dim h As LongPtr
Do
    hwnd = FindWindow("IEFrame", "ACSMAGAM - Internet Explorer") ' main window
    DoEvents
     Debug.Print Hex(hwnd)
    Sleep 200
Loop Until hwnd Or Now > timeout

Debug.Print Hex(hwnd)

  Child = FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", "") ' pop up
  Debug.Print Hex(Child)
 SetForegroundWindow (Child)

Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal Child) ' here comes the error
Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "&Apri")

Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
InvokePattern.Invoke
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd start with `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, and then `Dim hwnd As LongPtr, Child As LongPtr` before trying anything else. `Child` is implicitly a `Variant`, so if it overflows a `Long` it will get silently promoted to a `Double`.

Comment: Ok now it Works!!!! Thanks a lot!!!